# How to make git generate short commands on interactive git rebase

Tags: git

How to configure git so on interactive rebase it generates

```
p 3abc67f AAA
p 2b9c0ac BBB
```

instead of

```
pick 3abc67f AAA
pick 2b9c0ac BBB
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a config option called `rebase.abbreviateCommands`, which does what you want. This config option was introduced in [v2.16.0](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.16.0.txt#L126). In shell the command is:

`git config rebase.abbreviateCommands true`

[man git-config](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) says:

> If set to true, git rebase will use abbreviated command names in the
>   todo list resulting in something like this:
>
> ```
> p deadbee The oneline of the commit
> p fa1afe1 The oneline of the next commit
> ```

Comment: Tested, works great!

Answer (score 1):

Closest I've gotten is this:

`echo "let @i = 'gg0/# Rebase^Mkkvvlvgg^Vlllx0'" >> ~/.vimrc`

Then once in vim I do `@i`.